# SVG images not loading on Chrome (sometimes)

Tags: html, css, image, google-chrome, svg

Hi i have started converting a lot of my sites old image to SVG format and i cannot get them to display in the page.

The images do load if I open the image seperatly and then view the page after opening it. The SVG's are in the **correct file path** that I am referencing but nothing appears. Although on some refreshes it does appear.

```
<img class="padlock-img" src="content/img/cf/padlock.svg" alt="">
<img src="content/img/tips/progress.svg" alt="">
<img class="padlock-img" src="content/img/cf/padlock.svg" alt="">
```

### Here are some of my examples

[Example of one of the SVG's](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JYOQBy)

### Attempts

1. I have attemted turning src into `xlink:href` and this stopped the images from loading at all
2. I have tested this on 3 other browsers and the images load it is only happening on *chrome* on localhost and on file://

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: are you using wordpress? if yes, you need to edit your .htaccess and insert a code for svg. Reference: http://kaioa.com/node/45

Comment: I am not using wordpress, it is a local project at the minute not hosted on a server is is on file:// (this could be the issue?)

Comment: are you sure the link is correct? as you saying that is local, supposed to work

Comment: The links are correct - revision its only happening on chrome

Comment: Any warnings/errors in Chrome's javascript console?

Comment: No errors int h console sorry

Comment: Your image has exactly the same issue that Thomas Byy has prompted you before. Just change the "xlink:href="data:img/png;base64..." to "xlink:href="data:image/png;base64..." in your inline PNG image inside the SVG tag. BTW embedding PNG images in SVG should be done only if it's not possible otherwise.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When using SVG in Chrome, you need to make sure that your root tag has `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"`

### Edit

I haven't been able to find the problem, but one alternative would be

`<object data="yours.svg" type="image/svg+xml"></object>`

this seems to do the trick for all browsers.

Comment: I have this tag on all my svg's anyway still doesnt wokr

Comment: its in question now :)

Answer (score 4):

For what it's worth I had an image like this

`<img src="public/image/circles/circle.svg" class="circle_img" />`

If you open the svg in an editor I changed

`xlink:href="data:img/png;base64` to `xlink:href="data:image/png;base64`