# JSP page is not running in other systems in the same network

Tags: java, jsp

I have developed a jsp page which is running perfectly in my system. But when I access this URL from another system in the same network some features are not available. Precisely, I have an SVG image which should be displayed and some other information along with it, which is coming from a hardware.

When I try to access from other systems this SVG is not displaying. But other information is correct. I cant find any error in my web console or eclipse console. What could be the reason?

Comment: Check web-console for script related issue if any.

Comment: Please write detailed info, for example browser may cause the problem. Also you may check the browser console.

Comment: I stop you right there, the client don't have anything to do with the JSP. The JSP is on the server and stays on it. Explain what is not working, I would guess some javascript

Comment: This is your browser that don't read those SVG correctly (that can only be the browser since your a on the same network) . See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33215668/svg-images-not-loading-on-chrome-sometimes). A quick research would have been simpler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing any of the code or your project structure. This sounds like a url problem. Sometimes relative urls to certain resources will not load if they are not in the correct directory. For example..

Imagine on your jsp page your svg image is at

```
/images/image.svg
```

Well this resource will not be accessible if the URL is pointing at `/users/profiles/feed/`

What you have to do in these cases is make sure that all your resources are absolute urls, or jump back directories like so:

```
../images/image.svg
```

or if you're up 2 directories

```
../../images/image.svg
```