# Chrome doesn't displays SVG image sometimes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, svg

I am using the  library- https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-img-http-src to pass the byte array response of my authenitcated api to the http-src directive like this - :

```
<img class="img-responsive" ng-show="vm.imageUrl !='' " http-src="{{vm.imageUrl}}" alt="user_profile"  />
```

the image url points to an API i wrote that returns a byte array with the header Content-Type set based on file extension, so for svg images I am returning content type as image/svg+xml , it works for some svgs , but doesn't display some other svgs. I am not sure how to handle this, or differentiate between the svg files and render them accordingly, by using some other solution, and ng-show/hide (i tried using object tag also based on - [SVG images not loading on Chrome (sometimes)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33215668/svg-images-not-loading-on-chrome-sometimes) , but that doesn't work too).
Alternatively, is there any way to make sure the svg is always displayed correctly ?

EDIT 1 - the images display correctly always in Firefox
EDIT 2 - fixed a typo in the question images/svg+xml --> image/svg+xml

Comment: *"content type as images/svg+xml"* the correct MIME type is `image/svg+xml`. But I doubt that's the issue. Can you provide the response content of one such failing image?

Comment: sorry it was a typo in my question, I am returning image/svg+xml only , here's the response headers for the failing image - HTTP/1.1 200
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, PUT, PATCH, OPTIONS, DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Content-Type: image/svg+xml
Content-Length: 9391

Comment: "response content", not headers ;-) and in the question would be better, also if you can repro with a smaller file than 9KB that would be great

Comment: not able to find any other svg right now that is failing for display , i just randomly came across the particular svg, and noticed the issue, also the response content is all gibberish and not readable, may be I will upload the image itself in the question?

Comment: stackoverflow is not allowing to upload svg file, anyway, here's the file - https://github.com/soumitragoswami-eee48/stackoverflowfilerepo/blob/master/images.svg

Comment: one more interesting thing is , if I make the content-type as image/png for this particular image, its rendering in chrome

Comment: yes that file is actually a JPEG file, see the JFIF at the beginning of the binary data?

Comment: oh ok, sorry i don't have much experience working with different image formats, so didn't notice that, so is there any way i can catch this in my java code and return the correct content type or can something be done to remedy this in the JS code?

Comment: your api needs to catch it